# An action that runs after each post in the loop on index/archive page?

Tags: loop, actions

Is there an Action/a Filter that runs just after each post/post excerpt is displayed on these 2 pages? I use `the_content` and `get_the_excerpt` currently, but `the_content` causes a conflict with some other plugin (hence executing my function twice so the content is displayed twice) and setting the priority isn't working!

Note: I've tried `the_post`, but it runs before each post in the loop on these 2 pages.

**Update:**

My plugin adds a custom markup with icons after the post content using:
`the_content`- for single post/page and as some themes use `the_content('Read More')` on index/archive pages

`get_the_excerpt` - for index/archive pages

The plugin Advanced Excerpt adds some options for post excerpts, and allows the user to set the excerpt length from the settings. When the post length is less than the set excerpt length (via AEs settings), my markup is doubled! When I comment out `the_content` from my code, the conflict goes off, but without `the_content` how would I make my plugin work on single page/posts and also with some themes which use `the_content('Read More')` on index/archive pages?
I guess it happens because AE calls `the_content` instead of `the_excerpt` when the post length is less than the set excerpt length, hence resulting in a double call. I tried setting the priority of my filter function high, so that it runs after AE's filter function, but no luck!
Hence trying a workaround! I hope this clears the question!

Comment: Please explain the problem you're having with the function being called twice, i'd suggest working to fix that issue instead of working around it(sounds like a plugin or custom code is hooking a filter wrongly).

Comment: Edited question...

Comment: I think you should be working with the_content filter instead of the action.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Thanks man! Actually the filter seemed right, the issue was with the quotes and double quotes order, I was putting the html string in double quotes and the attributes in single, when it should be the other way round, fixed it, and the problem disappeared! Accepting your answer! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a dedicated action, but you could prevent double processing with an internal cache in your function.

Pseudo code:

```
function content_filter( $content )
{
    static $cache = array();
    $id           = get_the_ID();

    if ( in_array( $id, $cache ) )
    {
        return $content; // we did this already
    }

    $cache[] = $id;

    return $content . 'your awesome extra';
}
```